# How to create a 2D array of "-" in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I want to create the following looking 2D array of "-"

[image]

I attempted something like this but it did not work (for 10 by 10)

```c
char table[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        strcpy(table[10][i], "-");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to fill the 2D array, or print the pattern ?

Comment: `strcpy(table[10][i], "-");` -> `for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){table[i][j] = '-';}`

Comment: @wohlstad I want to fill the 2D array in order to create a coordinate system.

Comment: @StevenOh stop using c++ compiler to compile C code

Comment: @StevenOh Better to use text rather than a picture.  Please update and with the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole 2D array?

If not strings, use `memset(table, '-', sizeof table);` to fill every byte with `'-'`. No `for` loop needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
char table[10][10];

for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]); i ++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(table[i]); j++)
    {
        table[i][j] =  `-`);
    }
}
```

or `memset(table, '-', sizeof(table))`

If you want to have 10 strings (null character terminated)

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(table) / sizeof(table[0]); i ++){
    memset(table[i], `-`, sizeof(table[i]) - 1);
    table[i][sizeof(table[i]) - 1] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not advocating this for portability, but if you're using GCC, you can initialize at the declaration using the following [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

```
char table[10][10] = { [0 ... 9] = {[0 ... 9] = '-'} };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jozohnbzE)

(blatant ripoff of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207702/3476780))

Comment: what if `char (*table)[10] = malloc(10 * sizeof(*table));`?

Comment: @0___________ what of it? That's completely different than what's presented by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using strcpy we can assign values like this // table[i][j]= '-'; //

printf("%c",table[i][j]); //It is used to print characters//

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

char table[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        table[i][j]= '-';  //instead of using strcpy we can assign values like this//
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",table[i][j]); //It is used to print characters//
    }
    printf("\n"); //It is used to have a new line//
}  
return 0;
}
```